# Sort multiple columns and return table within Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I'm doing some analysis on customers behaviors upon using internet banking versus offline channel.

---

**I have imported excel database into pandas DataFrame**

```
#Read Excel file using pandas
excel_file = 'Analytic.xlsx'
analytic = pd.read_excel(excel_file)
analytic
```

---

**Result**
[image: Imgur]

---

**Problems**

The column `THANG_COGD` and `amnd_state` contains *the number of transaction months* and *the status of the users whether they have internet banking or not* respectively. Anyway, I want to *sort* the data by the column `THANG_COGD` that has value `0` and the column `amnd_state` that has value `A` and still print out the corresponding table

I can do this in Excel by simple creating a table and use the `sort functionality` in Excel to do so like shown

[image: Imgur]

As you can see the column `THANG_COGD` has been sorted as shown (`amnd_state` as well)

---

**Questions**

1. How can I do the same thing with `pandas`?

P/s: this is a dummy variable so there is no worries for data exploit

Comment: I think need `df = df.sort_values('THANG_COGD')`

Comment: what I mean is that when I try to use `df = df.sort_values('THANG_COGD')` it still shows values bigger than 0. My question is that are there any ways that I can only get the value 0 in my new table?

Comment: Check if compare numeric values by `print(df.dtypes)`